# Unable to start Netty in spring boot 2.5.13

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor

I have a spring boot application based on reactor but it can't be launched on Window 10 although it works fine on Linux. It failed to start Netty. This application uses spring boot 2.5.13 now. This issue doesn't exist for the old spring boot 2.3.

The exception was thrown by reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet.

Is there any config change that could fix this problem? So far, it looks to me like that this problem came from the reactor library and I can't fix by any config change.

Here is the exception stack.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start Netty
 at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer.start(NettyWebServer.java:108)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.WebServerManager.start(WebServerManager.java:55)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:40)
 at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
 ... 14 common frames omitted
 Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.lang.InterruptedException
 at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:392)
 at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:128)
 at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1731)
 at reactor.netty.transport.ServerTransport.bindNow(ServerTransport.java:145)
 at reactor.netty.transport.ServerTransport.bindNow(ServerTransport.java:130)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer.startHttpServer(NettyWebServer.java:145)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer.start(NettyWebServer.java:100)
 ... 17 common frames omitted
 Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block has been interrupted
 at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:130)
 ... 22 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1367)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:278)
 at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:121)
 ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please format your exception so that the question can be more readable.
Have you checked if it is not the dependency version specific issue?

Comment: Thanks. @SyedMainulHasan I have used {} to format the code but the code is in one line. reactor lib came with spring-boot 2.5.13 and I didn't include the reactor lib in the Maven pom file manually. How do I know it is not the dependency version specific issue?

Comment: May I get your repository url, so I can try in my local? I am using windows, and also have ubuntu, so I hope I can try in both environment.

Comment: Thanks. @SyedMainulHasan I don't have a repo url for this project yet. Let me check if I can create one. Do you think what could cause this problem?